# Looking for a dead-simple method for "locking" and "unlocking" a folder with Python on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, directory, permissions, attributes

I wrote a simple python3 script which runs on Windows and iterates through a "lockbox" folder and all of its sub-folders, and either encrypts or decrypts all the files therein. I want to add the feature that after it encrypts all the files, it somehow "locks" the lockbox folder, so that no files can be added/removed/modified, until they are decrypted again. This obviously entails the feature of "unlocking" the lockbox folder when files within are decrypted.

I am hoping for some simple command to "lock" and "unlock" the lockbox folder at the appropriate point in the running of the program.

As a bonus, I would like this to also be something which is "portable," meaning that if I put this lockbox folder on a usb stick, it will remain locked or unlocked, as the case may be, when I plug it into different machines. This isn't strictly necessary, but would be desired if possible.

Comment: Windows doesn't have anything quite like the Unix immutable file attribute/flag. Its readonly file attribute prevents deleting a file or directory, which is impossible anyway for a non-empty directory, and readonly prevents modifying file data, including any named $DATA streams in a file or directory (e.g. "dirname:streamname:$DATA"). It does not prevent modifying metadata such as the name, [extended] attributes, security, and reparse data. And, for a directory, it does not prevent adding and removing files and directories from its index, which is considered to be metadata about files.

Comment: If the filesystem supports security, you could rewrite the SACLs with an inherited mandatory label that denies write-up access to users that are below system integrity level (S-1-16-16384). So standard users and administrators will only have read and execute access -- unless an administrator enables SeRestorePrivilege (default disabled) and uses backup semantics.

Comment: I didn't fully understand much of what you said. It does seem, however, that this "readonly file attribute" may be of use. So, could I set a directory for readonly, and thereby prevent adding/removing/modifying any files it contains? Or, failing that, could I individually set each file to readonly, in order to prevent them each from being modified/moved/deleted?

Comment: If either of these would work, how could I implement this in python? How could I set a file or folder to be readonly, and how could I later remove that attribute...as simply as possible?

Comment: As I said, the readonly attribute does not prevent adding or removing files from a directory, and it does not prevent modifying metadata such as the readonly attribute itself and the filename (i.e. moving the file). It only protects files from being deleted and their data from being modified.

Comment: In Linux, filesystems such as ext4 support an immutable file attribute that requires super-user access to set (e.g. `sudo chattr +i filename`), and unlike readonly in Windows, making a directory immutable prevents adding, removing files, or renaming files in the directory. If this attribute was applied recursively in Linux, the directory would effectively be locked. The closest to that in Windows is my suggestion to recursively add a system-level mandatory label that denies write-up access, but the filesystem needs to support security, such as NTFS but not FAT32 or exFAT.

Comment: You can modify Windows file security in Python with `win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo`, from the PyWin32 package. To set a mandatory label at system level, you need to run as SYSTEM (e.g. from a service or task) or impersonate SYSTEM (e.g. as an admin, enable SeDebugPrivilege, open the session csrss.exe process with limited-query access, and then open and impersonate its access token).

Comment: If I can't accomplish the things I mentioned, then what would be the point of this? Or can I, using what you just wrote? I admit I am a bit confused at this point.